# CSS Divs Floated "Cards" in Wrap

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this basic scenario setup where I am trying to float divs inside of a wrap.  It is working nicely, however the simple effect I am trying to achieve isn't cooperating when the divs have variable heights.  I have researched this a bunch tried to apply a clearfix to the 3rd card without success.  The only success I've had is actually injecting another div after the 3rd card with a style of clear both.  However this is not an approach I want to take as I don't want to change any of the clean markup.  Thoughts on the best way to get this done?  I don't mind using a simple bit of JS/jQuery if necessary.

Desired:

[image]

Current:
http://andrewherrick.com/spike/floatcards/

Comment: wouldn't a simple css/ display: inline-block; for the cards do the trick? (without messing with float)

Comment: No I want the space.  Basically each row has three cards in it.  The card with the max height in that row determines where the below it starts.

Comment: Since when is using a "clear:both div" considered unclean?  Do you believe using a little JavaScript/jQuery to do this is more clean than using CSS alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but couldn't you simply add a "clear: both" to the 4th card?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

Add `clear: both` to the `3n+1` elements, using `.card:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: both }` or manually adding a class where needed.

**Solution 2:**

Instead of `float: left` on `.card`, use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top`. You'll also need to reduce the `margin-right` to `16px`.

If you need to support IE7, then `display: inline-block` needs to be `display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1`.

Comment: +1: solution 2 is truly superior. (Actually, it brings the problem of white-space between html elements... but.)

Answer (score 1):

You must define the "rows" somehow. You can set the same height of each div (thus setting row-height), or you can place a null height separator, or you can set `clear:left` for every 3rd div starting from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution 1*

If you're really averse to touching your mark-up, you could use some jQuery as such (Thanks to thirtydot for the tip):

**Jquery**

```
$('.card:nth-child(3n+1)').css('clear','left');
```

---

*Solution 2*

It might be cleaner (and more backwards-compatible) to just slightly alter your HTML.
Perhaps wrap each row in its own wrapper, with a clearfix applied to that.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/sh4fR/

You'll need to add the 'clearfix' CSS code. See the fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="cards clearfix">
        <div class="card">
            1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            2 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            3 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cards clearfix">
        <div class="card">
            4 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            5 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            6 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript can be simplified to `$('.card:nth-child(3n+1)').css('clear','left');`.

Answer (score 1):

`clear:both` set with an `nth-child` selector is what you are after.

You can dynamically add a class, using the `nth-child` selector with jQuery for older browsers that don't support it natively: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:nth-child`](http://css-tricks.com/5452-how-nth-child-works/) selector in combination with `clear:both`. The following will clear every third card. This will work reliably since you're using a fixed width (910px).

```
.card:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

Simply add the rule to your existing CSS. Tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YUsW/2/)